# Python: Removing whitespace from multiple lines of a string

Tags: python, list, whitespace, sequence, output

So I need the output of my program to look like:

```
ababa
ab ba 
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
that is it followed by a lot of spaces .
 no dot at the end
The largest run of consecutive whitespace characters was 47.
```

But what I am getting is:

```
ababa

ab ba

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
that is it followed by a lot of spaces .
no dot at the end
The longest run of consecutive whitespace characters was 47.
```

When looking further into the code I wrote, I found with the `print(c)` statement that this happens:

```
['ababa', '', 'ab           ba ', '', '                                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'that is it followed by a lot of spaces                         .', '                                               no dot at the end']
```

Between some of the lines, theres the `, '',`, which is probably the cause of why my print statement wont work.

How would I remove them? I've tried using different list functions but I keep getting syntax errors.

This is the code I made:

```
  a = '''ababa

    ab           ba 

                                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
that is it followed by a lot of spaces                         .
                                               no dot at the end'''


c = a.splitlines()
print(c)

#d = c.remove(" ") #this part doesnt work
#print(d)

for row in c:
    print(' '.join(row.split()))

last_char = ""
current_seq_len = 0
max_seq_len = 0

for d in a:
    if d == last_char:
        current_seq_len += 1
        if current_seq_len > max_seq_len:
            max_seq_len = current_seq_len
    else:
        current_seq_len = 1
        last_char = d
    #this part just needs to count the whitespace

print("The longest run of consecutive whitespace characters was",str(max_seq_len)+".")
```

Comment: What kind of logic creates `" xxxxxxxx"` out of `"      xxxxxxxx"` ??

Comment: Side note: the `remove` method *modifies* the list and returns `None`. Hence you should *not* do `d = c.remove('')` but simply: `c.remove('')` and afterwards `c` will have **one** less empty string. To remove all empty strings via `remove` do: `for _ in range(c.count('')): c.remove('')` (By the way: the empty string is `''`, i.e. quote-quote, without any space. In your case you where removing a single space string: `' '` quote-space-quote and you probably got some `ValueError`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex time:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"([\n ])\1*", r"\1", a))
#>>> ababa
#>>>  ab ba 
#>>>  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#>>> that is it followed by a lot of spaces .
#>>>  no dot at the end
```

`re.sub(matcher, replacement, target_string)`

Matcher is `r"([\n ])\1*` which means:

```
([\n ]) → match either "\n" or " " and put it in a group (#1)
\1*     → match whatever group #1 matched, 0 or more times
```

And the replacement is just

```
\1 → group #1
```

You can get the longest whitespace sequence with

```
max(len(match.group()) for match in re.finditer(r"([\n ])\1*", a))
```

Which uses the same matcher but instead just gets their lengths, and then `max`s it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, your easiest solution would be using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
c= [item for item in a.splitlines() if item != '']
```

If you wish to make it slightly more robust by also removing strings that only contain whitespace such as `'    '`, then you can alter it as follows:

```
c= [item for item in a.splitlines() if item.strip() != '']
```

You can then also join it the list back together as follows:

```
output = '\n'.join(c)
```

Comment: `if item.strip()` is enough. No need to add `!= ""`.

Comment: While its true, I prefer to use the explicit form for readability's sake.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved with the built-in [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
c = filter(None, a.splitlines())
# or, more explicit
c = filter(lambda x: x != "", a.splitlines())
```

The first variant will create a list with all elements from the list returned by `a.splitlines()` that do not evaluate to `False`, like the empty string.
The second variant creates a small anonymous function (using [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)) that checks if a given element is the empty string and returns `False` if that is the case. This is more explicit than the first variant.

Another option would be to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that achieves the same thing:

```
c = [string for string in a.splitlines if string]
# or, more explicit
c = [string for string in a.splitlines if string != ""]
```

Comment: This would work. However if one of the items in the list is an empty string i.e. just white space such as `'        '`, then it would not be filtered out.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina If a string contains white-space then it is **not** an empty string. To check whether a string is empty or space-only simply use `lambda x: x.strip()`). `strip()` without arguments removes all the consecutive spaces from the left and right of the string, resulting in an empty string if the string is space-only.

Comment: @Bakuriu this in fact the approach I suggested in my answer.

Comment: But from what I could gather from the OP's question he was only dealing with true empty strings (""), that's why I didn't include `strip` here.